# How to create dynamic dropdown list in excel through flutter Syncfusion using package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, export-to-excel, syncfusion

I am trying to create some dropdown lists in Excel using dynamic JSON data through flutter and I am using syncfusion package. Here is my code.

```
final Map<String, dynamic> map = {"Category":'Electronic',"SubCategory":['Laptop','Mobile'};

Future<void> createExcel()async{
final Workbook workbook = Workbook();
final Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];

int col = 1;
map.forEach((k, v) {
  sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, col).setText(k.replaceAll("\"", ""));
  DataValidation cell = sheet.getRangeByIndex(2, col,500,1).dataValidation;
  cell.allowType = ExcelDataValidationType.user;
  cell.listOfValues = v;
    col++;
});


final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();
workbook.dispose();

final String path = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final String fileName = "$path/Products.xlsx";
final File file = File(fileName);
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
OpenFile.open(fileName);
```

}

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem has been solved. Actually I was putting wrong last column index

Comment: welcome good to know that your problem is solved